# Accessing available app updates in Play Store app through a shortcut

Tags: google-play-store

It seems that Google is making it more and more difficult for users to check manually for the updates, trying to encourage people to keep automatic updates on. While I don't mind the automatic updates, I do like to see what changes have been done in each update (when the devs are kind enough to mention it), just to be aware when a new feature has been introduced or a bug fixed.

Currently, these are the steps needed in order to reach the page where I see the available updates:

1. Open Play Store app
2. Tap on the User icon
3. Manage apps & device
4. Updates available
5. Pending downloads page

Ideally, this could all be a one-click operation.

My launcher, Nova, offers shortcuts to app-specific actions in order to access certain app features or parts directly. Play Store has many listed, but it seems that none is taking you to the newly-introduced Pending downloads page.

Is there a way to figure out a unique shortcut that would take one to the "Pending downloads" page?

[Tap to see the available updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9sUa.jpg)

["Pending downloads" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsdYi.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Alecxs, but that's unfortunately not what I need. I already tried using Shortcut Maker as well as Nova launcher's built-in features that do pretty much the same thing as the app you referenced, but the problem is that GP does not seem to list Pending Downloads as one of the links that can be accessed via the available shortcuts in any of the mentioned programs.

Comment: I think that question should returned to stackoverflow as it seems you are asking about which is the responsible intent/activity name of google play apk for pending updates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intent for Google Play Store "Manage apps & device" (My apps / Updates) does not work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540618/intent-for-google-play-store-manage-apps-device-my-apps-updates-does-not)

Comment: Actually, it does, thank you.
The author of that question mentioned that they don't enter exactly into the Pending Downloads, but I don't mind having to tap once more to enter those.  This is still an improvement over what I had to do before 

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @alecxs  for pointing me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540618/intent-for-google-play-store-manage-apps-device-my-apps-updates-does-not), that does almost exactly what I need.

The GPS intent is as follows:

```
Action  : com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS
Package : com.android.vending
Class   : com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity
Target  : Activity
```

I used [Shortcut Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rk.android.app.shortcutmaker) to make a link to the Manage Apps & Devices' Overview page, which makes my life easier now.

**Edit: The method above stopped working at some point.
Now I'm using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627961/2829288) and I'm happy again, and additionally, it's one app less on my phone.**

Comment: I am not seeing the `VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS` activity anymore. Has something changed?

Comment: @Bijan it seems it did. I haven't used this setup in some time. Now I'm back and I too see that the above method doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Bijan, I posted this on your own question, but here it is in case someone wonders in here. Try this approach: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627961/2829288